# Create this query in JPA - Spring boot app

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a dynamic query in my spring boot app using JPA Repository to create query to return some data from PostgreSQL

```
ID  Name   Status      Mode
1   Test1  Processed   Mode A
2   Test2  In-Flight   Mode B
3   Test3  Processed   Mode B
4   Test4  In-Flight   Mode A
5   Test5  Processed   Mode A
```

This is the table

```
Mode    Processed In-Flight
Mode A  2         1
Mode B  1         1
```

Above is the return needed

And I found a query mentioned below

```
Select mode, 
       count(*)
 filter (where messagelist.routestatus = 'Processed') as processed,
       count(*)
 filter (where messagelist.routestatus = 'In-Flight') as in_flight,
 count(*)
 filter (where messagelist.routestatus = 'Failed') as failed
from messagelist
group by mode
order by mode;
```

Need to change this query to dynamic java query
This 'mode' might be changed to some other thing corresponding to user input SO I can't use native query
Need to create query dynamicqally

Comment: JPA deals with java objects; you've posted a JPQL(HQL?) but only shown us the Database table - we would need to be able to see the java entity classes to turn/change the given query into one returning what you want. How are you building 'that' query anyway, and how much change do you need - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries for some idea using criteria expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try Jao Query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT c.year, COUNT(c.year) FROM Comment AS c GROUP BY c.year ORDER BY c.year DESC")
```